# Paw app query request

Tags: paw-app

Hi I am attempting to initiate a query to my backend on Kinvey which is backed by a MongoDB.  They require passing URL parameters as such:
?query={"firstName":"James"}
I have tried every imaginable way of setting up these parameters in PAW but either get a success response with no filtering of the data or an error message of URL not supported when I try using a Raw Query String.

I have ran the query using their (Kinvey) backend API interface and it works fine in filtering the results so the problem definitely lies within PAW. I am currently using version 3.0.9.  Any suggestions or is this just a bug that needs to be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried this setup in Paw and I have a few recommendations:

- Paw will URL-encode the chars `{` and `"` as you can see if you open the HTTP preview in the bottom panel

[image: Paw URL encodes query parameters]

- Trying to send a similar query via Chrome (to test with another app to make sure Paw behaves correctly), I see that the query is URL encoded (try this query `https://echo.paw.cloud/?query={"firstName":"James"}` you'll see that the browser actually URL-encodes the characters `{` and `"` when sending. So the behavior is the same with Paw.
- I don't think these two chars (`{` and `"`) are valid HTTP if they are not URL-encoded, so I'm sure your server is expecting them encoded anyway
- Testing this exact query in Paw, works for me, so please try these exact steps: go to URL Params, in the first column enter `query` and `{"firstName":"James"}` in the second column. Then using the HTTP preview mentioned above, make sure Paw is sending the request you're expecting.
- Lastly, it's more like a tip, but as your value is JSON, I recommend that you use the JSON dynamic value to generate the JSON. It will be visually better for you, and will make sure you send valid JSON. For that, right click on the value field, and select Values > JSON. Here's some example:

[image: Inline serialized JSON in your requests in Paw]

Comment: Micha, thanks a bunch!  Using you first recommendation works perfect and filters as desired.  As far as JSON dynamic values, I had tried that earlier and it didn't work.  I just retried again just to be sure it I hadn't messed something up and it does not work.  There is no filtering and the entire collection content is returned.  Weird.